# How do I combine wget, sort and save into a new filename?

Tags: ubuntu, rename, sort, wget

I am trying to combine several commands.

First I use: wget xyz.com/zxc.txt

Then I unscramble the file using: `sort -n zxc.txt`

Lastly, I save the unscrambled file as a new file: `sort -n zxc.txt > qwerty.txt`

How do I combine all 3 steps into one line of code?

Comment: Do you actually need the unsorted `zxc.txt` file? if not, use the `-O` option of `wget` to output the content to `stdout` i.e. `wget -O- xyz.com/zxc.txt`, and pipe that to `sort`

Answer (score 2):

[steeldriver had a perfectly good idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391383/how-do-i-combine-wget-sort-and-save-into-a-new-filename#comment697648_391383), which I'll flesh out here:

This downloads the file you listed, but instead of saving it, pipes it to stdout `-O-` means "output to `-`"; `-` is shorthand for stdout. That stdout is then piped to sort; the sorted output is then redirected into the final filename.

```
wget -O- xyz.com/zxc.txt | sort -n > qwerty.txt
```